# Replace numbers inside a string using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace `Html.fromHtml("&#160") + "| Guys hi " + Pattern.compile("\\d+")` with a "hey". But, my code doesn't want to do that :/ What should I change?

My code:

```
myString.replace(Html.fromHtml("&#160") + "| Guys hi " + Pattern.compile("\\d+"), "hey");
```

Explanation:

- `"&#160"` represents a space in HTML
- `Pattern.compile("\\d+")` finds any number at the end of string.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're using regex correctly... (maybe?)

Comment: Erm... What...?

Comment: @MateusA. then, how can you explain my code not working?

Comment: What is this `Pattern.compile("\\d+")` supposed to do? Regex (or Patterns) is for text matching/validating... It won't be turned into a number/text.

Comment: @MateusA. by using `Pattern.compile("\\d+")` I hope to detect numbers in my string

Comment: `Pattern.compile("\\d+")` only creates pattern which *describes* one or more digits, but it doesn't automatically *find* it. It is your job to decide how to use it. From what I see you could be looking for `replaceAll(regex, replacement)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String` replaceAll takes a regular expression, `String` replace does not. Using a pattern is an *alternative* option (not a supplementary one). Also, `String`(s) are immutable. You want something like,

```
myString = myString.replaceAll(Html.fromHtml("&#160") + "- Guys hi \\d+", "hey");
```

**or**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Html.fromHtml("&#160") + "- Guys hi \\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
myString = m.replaceAll("hey");
```

Comment: I'm testing this, I'm encountering a few issues. I'll be back to you soon!

Comment: It works, but I made a typing mistake in the question. It's now edited. The `-` is supposed to be a `|`. Using your first line of code, the `|` doesn't get replaced. How can we fix this?

Comment: Escape a literal `|` with ``\`` like ``\\|``.